# CSS - absolute positioning in iphone? (phonegap, jqtouch)

Tags: iphone, css, ios, cordova, jqtouch

I'm trying to position a div over a google map in an iphone app built with phonegap. It shows up fine on the web (http://presentations.superfaddev.com/ifad/v2/ifad.html#Contact - Click on locations and you'll see the map overlay of our 3 locations).

However, in my app the overlay is nowhere to be seen, which I'm guessing has something to do with absolute positioning or something. Anyone know how to fix this, or what the best way to position one thing over another in iPhone is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to put position:relative; to the container.
Position absolute takes origin from the first parent element positioned relative.

Comment: half correct.  position relative "position[s] it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position#section_3 i.e. the first parent element that does not have static positioning.